# using gloss error unknown GLUT entry glutInit

Tags: windows, haskell, glut, gloss

Hey I am trying to use gloss library but I always get this error: `Exception: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)`
This is my code:

```
module Pruebas where

import Graphics.Gloss

window :: Display
window = InWindow "Nice Window" (200, 200) (10, 10)

background :: Color
background = white

drawing :: Picture
drawing = circle 80

final :: IO ()
final = display window background drawing
```

I know that there are similar questions but I haven't been able to find a solution there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to have GLUT installed for some smaller openGL programs to function.If your using linux insalling freeglut will do the trick otherwise
[This](https://www.cs.csustan.edu/%7Ersc/SDSU/GLUTinstall.html) could help you install GLUT you can also check [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellgamedev/comments/4yi7y1/gloss_glut_and_windows/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it just seems to need the glut32.dll. I had exactly the same problem and I could finally solve it with that dll. Just put it next to your executable or in the same folder as you are running your command (like cabal-repl) if you're using ghci.